# URL Rewriting doesn't rewrite automatically

Tags: url, php

I have this simple redirection on my website and it does not rewrite my url automatically, I have to type manual other URL to access it, what could be the problem, do I need to have something enabled in php.ini, below is the rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^new-page-([^/]*)\.php$ /mypage.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing it in `.htaccess` you should also specify `RewriteBase /`.
Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^new-page-([^/]*)\.php$ mypage.php?name=$1 [L]
```

This rewrites `new-page-something.php` to`mypage.php?name=something` internally.

**ADDED:**

Perhaps you want this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^new-page-([^/]*)\.php$ mypage.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /mypage.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^\&]*)
RewriteRule ^mypage.php$ new-page-%1.php? [R,L]
```

The first added RewriteCond checks whether the real request is requesting for `/mypage.php` to prevent a redirect loop.
The second added RewriteCond is used to match the query string for use in RewriteRule.

Comment: So your server doesn't allow overriding in `.htaccess`.

Comment: does allow as once I access page just typing it, it does work. so when I access new-page-value.php it does open correct page but when I access mypage.php?name=value it does not bring up the previous one up it self.

Comment: I've added something, is that what you want?

Comment: still do the the same, just not rewriting and URL stays as mypage.php?name=

Comment: what happen if I would like to add 2nd value to that URL, how this code will have to rewritten?

Comment: @user974435 Change corresponding lines `RewriteRule ^new-page-([^/]*)-([^/]*)\.php$ mypage.php?name=$1&name2=$2 [L]`  `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^\&]*)`    `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name2=([^\&]*)`    
`RewriteRule ^mypage.php$ new-page-%1-%2.php? [R,L]`

Comment: it doesnt work :( where is that line missing RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /mypage.php

Comment: @user974435 that line doesn't need changing

Answer (score 1):

check your apache config (httpd.conf)
see whether it allowing to overriding the htaccess

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: thanks, I know all those. That must be on server side as on the other server does work

Answer (score 0):

I have the following link

> www.preparationweb.com/Aptitude/Discussion/index.php?qid=26

I like it to appear it as

> www.preparationweb.com/Aptitude/Discussion/26

Can you please provide me the code to be placed in .htaccess file according to the provided link. I have a godaddy hosting.