# Capture all instances of url inbetween / / but not if file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've learned a bit about MVC from working with a Code Igniter project at my job, and so I'm trying to accomplish this:

Before:
index.php
somepage.php
secondpage.php

All these files had "include(header) and include(footer) and so on...

Instead I want to capture what page the user is looking for from the url -> Redirect them to index, and always load header and footer in that one place, and the only thing that changes is the content.

So I did this with my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&child=$2&grandchild=$3&cousin=$4&aunt=$5&uncle=$6 [NC,QSA,L]
   RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&child=$2&grandchild=$3&cousin=$4&aunt=$5 [NC,QSA,L]
   RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&child=$2&grandchild=$3&cousin=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
   RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&child=$2&grandchild=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
   RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&child=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
   RewriteRule (.*^.css) index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

With the mindset if it works it's a start.. but it doesn't work. First i noticed my css not loading.. and apparently -f doesn't help so I added rules, but then /img/bg.png doesn't work either..

I hope it's apparent that I'm trying to capture whatever words are in between / / in the url and pass them on to index as parameters. Do you guys know if there are any smart rewrite rules that actually ignores the rewrite if file exists?

Comment: hmm this might work for not rewriting internal calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116087/url-rewriting-doesnt-rewrite-automatically I'll try it! :D

Answer (score 1):

The `RewriteCond`s are applied to the next, in your case the first, `RewriteRule` only. If you want to use it for every RewriteRule, you must duplicate it

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?) index.php?page=$1&child=$2&grandchild=$3&cousin=$4&aunt=$5&uncle=$6 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&child=$2&grandchild=$3&cousin=$4&aunt=$5 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?) index.php?page=$1&child=$2&grandchild=$3&cousin=$4 [QSA,L]
...
```

The `[NC]` flag is not needed here, because the pattern doesn't contain any alphabetic characters.

I also modified the pattern a bit, to use `^` for the beginning of the URL path and the non-greedy version `.*?`, which makes the captures stop at the first slash seen.

Comment: I didn't know Cond only apply for "next rule"!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my logic.
I now detect what page, and save the rest into variable settings, 
and this only works with thr ? after .* as you suggested:

Final current solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&settings=$2 [QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```