# Detecting what link was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have 2 links, both of them leading to contact page, however different fields will be displayed in the contact form, according to the clicked link. Is there a possibility to detect what link was clicked with the URL looking like that: `mysite.com/contact.html` instead of `mysite.com/contact.html?link=1`? Perhaps somehow with JavaScript?

Comment: You may use .htaccess to rewrite url links. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116087/url-rewriting-doesnt-rewrite-automatically

Comment: You can assign a cookie in the onclick event of each link then check the cookie in the contact page.

Comment: What's wrong with passing it in the url? Safest bet if you don't want to work with cookies that users may not accept.

Comment: @Cecil Thanks for your answer, however I'm not very good with editing server settings, so I prefer not to touch the .htaccess file...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Many people tend to block cookies, so I prefer "cookiless" solution :) Thnak you for your input!

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness Nothing wrong with that, of course, just wanted to keep the URL clean. But if no other solution found - will pass variables in the URL, of course. Thanks!

Comment: @Igal: I'm curious, do you have a link to up-to-date statistics about people blocking cookies? I've never seen anything rigorous on the subject, and certainly nothing recent. I'm just curious what the numbers really are.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder According to Opentracker.org, less than 5% block first-party cookies and up to 40% block/delete third-party cookies http://bit.ly/1i2AIMc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have three options (or two, depending on how you want to count):

1. The best thing, which is what you said you didn't want to do: Make the URLs slightly different (perhaps with a query string) and then look at `location` / `location.search` in the contact page to see what they clicked.

   It doesn't have to be as obvious as a bit query string parameter; it could be more subtle, like `example.com/contact.html` vs. `example.com/contactb.html`. If you want the same actual page served for both of those URLs, you can configure your server to make one an alias of the other.

   Note that this is better not just pragmatically (it works reliably), but because then the URLs of the two pages are different. Since the pages are different, having their unique identifier (their URL) be different makes sense.
2. This is a variant on #1: Instead of a query string or different page name, use a hash fragment, e.g. `example.com/contact.html#A` and `example.com/contact.html#B`. The contacts page can check for that via `location.hash. (Make sure you don't have any elements with the`id"A"`or`"B"`, so the page won't scroll down to them.)
3. Alternately, set information when the link is clicked that the contact page can look for. That could be a cookie with a short expiration, or [session storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute).

   Here's how the session storage would look. On the first page, setting the session variable:

   ```
   // (The value must be a string.)
   sessionStorage.contactType = "some value to tell you what contact type";
   ```

   On the contact page, retrieving the session variable:

   ```
   var contacttype = sessionStorage.contactType;
   ```

   Note that this is entirely client-side. See the link above for details.

Comment: As I see Igal is looking for a JavaScript based solution. Session variables are in higher level data storage as far as I know.

Comment: @PatarticsMilán: Check out the link. This is *web* session storage, entirely client-side, and accessed via JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not fixated on JavaScript only and I'm looking for various solutions to choose from. Cookies, for example, isn't the best solution, since many people tend to block them. Session storage or web storage might be a good solution. The question is: do mobile browsers, such as Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari, Dolphin, Puffin, Skyfire etc. support session storage and/or web storage?

Comment: @Igal: Yes, web storage is [very well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) on both desktop and mobile browsers.

Comment: @Igal: I added a new option #2. Good luck with things,

Comment: Great, thanks! Then I guess web storage is the best possible solution, will deal with that. Again, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your links like `class="detector"` and ids like `id="A"` and `id="B"` than use a jquery event to pass the info.

```
$('.detector').click(function(){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior
    location.href=$(this).attr('href') + '?link=' + $(this).attr('id');
});
```

This will work with as many links as you wish.

Comment: jQuery-only answers to non-jQuery questions are not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you're looking at doing this with javascript, but a server-side alternative (that will allow you more flexibility in the future):

Build a single php script that handles the contact form, which shows different form fields depending on the specific url. Let's assume it resides at `example.com/contact/index.php`.

Create a `.htaccess` file within the `/contact` folder with something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /contact/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^/]+)/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /contact/index.php?form=%1  [L]
```

What this does, is captures a virtual folder after `/contact/` and rewrites it as a url parameter to `index.php` (e.g. `index.php?form=sales`)

You can now visibly use links like these in your html:

- http://example.com/contact/sales
- http://example.com/contact/support

And in your contact form `index.php`, you can handle different `$_GET` parameters:

```
if (isset($_GET['sales']))
{
    //do this
}
else if (isset($_GET['support']))
{
    //do that
}
```

Some immediate benefits:

- You only need to manage one file, and it doesn't depend on a bunch of nested `include`s.
- The solution scales; it only requires a few `if` statements to handle another contact form variable.
- It's protected from client-side manipulation.